# Permission denied when accessing su

Tags: virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu on VirtualBox and I can't access Su.

When I type su and enter my password it says permission denied. I want to create and edit files through terminal so I need to do this.

Comment: Authentication failure is what I get

Answer (score 3):

Try using `sudo su` instead. That should work a little better for you.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I solved it. Just type Sudo -i

Comment: I'm glad you found something that works for you.. Typing `sudo` will indeed run a single command with superuser privileges. To enter superuser mode (to run multiple commands as root, without the need to type "sudo" for each one), you can use `sudo su`.